# How can I access an environment var in other modules

Tags: node.js, parameters, jwt

I use the jsonwebtoken module to Encode and Decode JWTs.
The Secret-passphrase is being saved in a config.yml file, which is being loaded in my main index.js Javascript and stored into an app Environment var `app.set('jwtToken', config.jwt.token)`.

How can I access this environment var in another module (for example the Auth-Route Module).
Can I pass it somehow to this file?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need access to your app instance to access the jwtToken var in app. Alternative for you would be to pass your jwtToken as an process environment variable via

```
JWT_TOKEN=xyz node server.js
```

Now you could access it via [process.env.JWT_TOKEN](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)

Comment: I think passing it as a process environment variable isnt a choice, since I cannot switch easily between the different configurations (prod, test, dev, ...) then?

How can I access the app instance? I pass the second module as an Express Router (module.exports = router).